# hibernate/jpa duplicate primary key with InheritanceType.JOINED

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have read many postings about similar errors, and tried all the suggestions, but the error I am encountering is still not resolved.

In a `spring mvc` app using `hibernate` and `jpa` with `InheritanceType.JOINED` above a MySQL database, I keep getting the following error when trying to persist a subclass:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '4' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

The error started with key values of `1`, then `2`, then `3`, then `4`, despite the fact that the parent table already has values up to `11`.  This makes me suspect that the `EntityManager.persist()` call for the subclass is somehow not seeing the primary key values of the parent table.  **But how can I fix this and resolve the error?**  Here is repository code that is being run when the error is thrown:

```
@Override
public void saveRIMOrganization(Organization myorg) throws DataAccessException{
    if (myorg.getHppid() == null) {this.em.persist(myorg);}//ERROR THROWN HERE
    else {this.em.merge(myorg);}
}
```

The annotations of the classes are next.  Note that I have also tried `strategy = "native"`, `strategy = "identity"`, and `strategy = "sequence"`, but I still get the same error.

```
@Entity(name = "rimInfrastructureRoot")
@Table(name = "rim_infrastructure_root")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class InfrastructureRoot {
    @Id
    @Column(name="hppid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "native")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    private Long hppid;

    public Long getHppid(){return hppid;}//non-compliant, added by jim
    public void setHppid(Long i){hppid=i;}//non-compliant, added by jim
    //other stuff
}

@Entity(name = "rimEntity")
@Table(name = "rim_entity")
public class rimEntity extends InfrastructureRoot{
//other stuff
}

@Entity(name = "rimOrganization")
@Table(name = "rim_organization")
public class Organization extends rimEntity {
}
```

The database tables are created by hbm2ddl, so I would need to make any necessary changes in the java/hibernate level, but I did a MySQL dump of the three tables corresponding with the above entities, and the ddl code is:

```
CREATE TABLE `rim_infrastructure_root` (
  `hppid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`hppid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `rim_entity` (
  `hppid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `classCode_HJID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`hppid`),
  KEY `FK_11bd6a37297d46389840550ae76` (`classCode_HJID`),
  KEY `FK_7c111383cf8e4134a047195a792` (`hppid`),
  KEY `FK_4dead31433c246b1b9706030d87` (`classCode_HJID`),
  KEY `FK_c14223423db54eb8abf4d778dd4` (`hppid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_c14223423db54eb8abf4d778dd4` FOREIGN KEY (`hppid`) REFERENCES `rim_infrastructure_root` (`hppid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_11bd6a37297d46389840550ae76` FOREIGN KEY (`classCode_HJID`) REFERENCES `cd` (`HJID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_4dead31433c246b1b9706030d87` FOREIGN KEY (`classCode_HJID`) REFERENCES `cd` (`HJID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_7c111383cf8e4134a047195a792` FOREIGN KEY (`hppid`) REFERENCES `rim_infrastructure_root` (`hppid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `rim_organization` (
  `hppid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`hppid`),
  KEY `FK_cc7e6250f02347dea615ebc287a` (`hppid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_cc7e6250f02347dea615ebc287a` FOREIGN KEY (`hppid`) REFERENCES `rim_entity`(`hppid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: It suggest that the primary key is already used in table. so truncate your database first and than try. might be helpful